# FFmpeg: use absolute path in "metadata=print:file="

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to extract frames of a video and therefore I want to print the metadata of the video to a text file first (to get the `scene\` value of each frame).

This already works for me with something like:

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='gte(scene,0)',metadata=print:file=scenescores.txt" -an -f null -
```

Because I'm using all this inside of a Java application I want to pass an absolute path (of an temp directory) to `print:file=` instead of the currently relative one which will write it to the root directory of the project.

But when I try to specify an absolute path like `D:\scenescores.txt` I get the following error:

```
[metadata @ 00000203282ff0c0] Unable to parse option value "scenescores.txt" as boolean
[metadata @ 00000203282ff0c0] Error setting option direct to value scenescores.txt.
[Parsed_metadata_1 @ 00000203269bdf00] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020328020840] Error initializing filter 'metadata' with args 'print:file=D:\scenescores.txt'
```

Is there any way to achieve printing to an absolute path? Am I missing some escape rules or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a lot with escaping different things and in the end it worked for me like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='gte(scene,0)',metadata=print:file=\'D:\scenescores.txt\'" -an -f null -
```

The difference is that the path is surrounded by `\'`.
Also I read that escaping `\` to `\\` or `/` can help sometimes.